# Firebase auth Redirect to Facebook app instead of website for login on mobile

Tags: firebase-authentication

Is it possible configure my firebase project so that if a user is on mobile and they need to log in, they are redirected to the facebook mobile app instead of the facebook website in their browser?. I thought iOS would automatically intercept the link but it just takes you to the facebook site. Users with the app installed might not already be logged in through their browser since they are used to using the app and i'd like to avoid the extra login step for them

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have this with Facebook, Twitter, Google and Github as well. I have set Brave as default browser and the login opens the website in the browser.